# Dynamically unprotect cells based on a date - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish the following:

1. Protect the sheet
2. Iterate through each row

- If Column 1 contains a date that is > 7 days before the current date then
- - unprotect column 3, 4, 5, 6 (within that row)
- - Otherwise do nothing

I've reworked some other examples I found online, but I've been far from successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Protects sheet unprotects rows > 7 days before the current date

```
function serveButNotProtect() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let p = sh.protect();
  const a = [];
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() - 7).valueOf();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let dv = new Date(r[0]);
    if (dv > dtv) {
      a.push(sh.getRange(i + 2, 3, 1, 4))
    }
  });
  if (a && a.length > 0) {
    p.setUnprotectedRanges(a);
  }
  let b = p.getUnprotectedRanges().map(rg => [rg.getA1Notation()]).sort((a, b) => {
    let va = parseInt(a[0].slice(1, a[0].indexOf(':')));
    let vb = parseInt(b[0].slice(1, b[0].indexOf(':')));
    return va - vb;
  });
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.getRange(1, 1, b.length, b[0].length).setValues(b);
}
```

Sheet0:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| 9/1/2022 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 9/2/2022 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 9/3/2022 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 9/4/2022 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 9/5/2022 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 9/6/2022 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 9/7/2022 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 9/8/2022 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 9/9/2022 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 9/10/2022 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 9/11/2022 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 9/12/2022 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 9/13/2022 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| 9/14/2022 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| 9/15/2022 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 9/16/2022 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 9/17/2022 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 9/18/2022 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 |
| 9/19/2022 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 9/20/2022 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |

Sheet1:

Unproted Ranges:

| A |
| --- |
| C8:F8 |
| C9:F9 |
| C10:F10 |
| C11:F11 |
| C12:F12 |
| C13:F13 |
| C14:F14 |
| C15:F15 |
| C16:F16 |
| C17:F17 |
| C18:F18 |
| C19:F19 |
| C20:F20 |
| C21:F21 |

Comment: I've just added this script, changed the name of the sheet name for "sh", ran the script - but I don't see any results (with no corresponding output on Sheet1).  Also, the sheet is not protected.  I must be missing something...

Comment: Do you have a Sheet0 and a Sheet1?

Comment: I can assure you that this code does in fact run

Comment: I have a "Timesheet" and a "Sheet1".  I just made 1 edit to the code.

const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Timesheet");
const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

Comment: My Sheet0 contains data and column 1 is a date.  Sheet1 is just used to display the unprotected rangers so it will get cleared and then written into.

Comment: Perhaps you should post an image of you sheets

Comment: It worked.  I had the function within the default myFunction().  I'm very new to this (adapting from VBA), so thanks.